# How to find rank 2 symmetric matrix?

Tags: matrices

I want to find a symmetric matrix $A = [a_{i,j}]$ that has exactly rank 2 and that satisfies the following rule:

1. for some $i \neq j$, we have $a_{i,j} = a_{j,i} \neq 0$
2. for others, $a_{i',j'} = 0$ for $i' \neq i$ and $j' \neq j$

Is there any source about finding such matrices? I've browsed the literature, but failed to find any...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Consider
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&\cdots&0\\ 1&0&0&\cdots&0\\0&0&0&\cdots&0\\ \vdots&\vdots&\vdots &\ddots&\vdots\\ 0&0&0&\cdots&0\end{bmatrix}.$$